# Unlock level 3 O-Powers?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

- Can I use level one O-Power to unlock level 3?
- Does it take longer than using level 2?
- Does it take longer to level up if you give O-Powers rather than self-use?
- How many times do you have to use it to upgrade from 2 to 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Not confirmed, but all current sources say yes.
- Yes.
- No, it doesn't take longer, *per say*, but it costs much less O-Power energy to send O-Powers to other people, so giving is more efficient.
- It takes around 30 uses of a L2 O-Power to receive the L3 O-Power